# Xpath copy and delete node

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm facing an xpath problem, I have to copy a child node to a parent node if this condition is checked : IdchildNode = IdparentNode.

My code :

```
string IDchildnode = "1492";

string xpathNodeToCopy = "/a:SL/a:Data/a:ChildNode[@id=\"" + IDchildnode + "\"]";
nodeToClone = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpathNodeToCopy, xnsm);

if (nodeToClone != null)
{
    nodeToCopy = nodeToClone.Clone();

    string xpathNodePlaceToCopy = "/a:SL/a:Sub/a:VolLevel/a:Bay/*/a:ParentNode[@lid=\"" + IDchildnode + "\"]";

    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes(xpathNodePlaceToCopy, xnsm);

    if (nodeList != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            nodeList[i].AppendChild(nodeToCopy);
            doc.Save(sourceFile);
        }
    }
}
```

A phenomenon that I don't understand happens, I put a breakpoint in my code and I check in parallel if in my XML document each element of my list is receiving a copy but :

First element, copy of the child is done, I refresh my xml document and I see the child has been copied. 
Second element, the child has been copied too BUT the child of the first element of the list has been deleted. 
Third element, the child has been copied BUT the child of the second element of the list has been deleted.

etc ...

For instance here a simplified view of my xml document when iteration reached i=1 :

```
<ItemParent id="1492"></ItemParent>
<ItemParent id="1492">
  <ItemChild id="1492"></ItemParent>
<ItemParent id="1492">
<ItemParent id="1492">
```

You can see here, my child which have been copied on the first ItemParent have been deleted.

I don't understand why in each iteration 't', child copied in itérération 't-1' is deleted. Especially when i save my xml document with "doc.Save(sourceFile)" at each iteration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how the DOM methods like `AppendChild` work, if the argument is located somewhere in the tree it is moved and not cloned. So you will have to make sure you do

```
nodeList[i].AppendChild(nodeToCopy.Clone());
```

to ensure a new copy is inserted for each item in your node list.